# Tool making by using python

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, arctoolbox

[image: I made this gui for my tool. where, input feature class = shape file input, Field = select some field from input given in input, area = area field from input, output feature class= output path]

My problem is that i want to solve one equation by using these inputs.

Equation is : (field*area)/total area where field= fields which are selected, Area= field of area, total area= total of area.

The result of this process is store in another new field. I am using python 9.3.

Give me some idea to solve this by using python.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new parameter for the output field. Then create an expression that handles your formula in the execute folder.
Something like this:

```
# Output Parameter
    Output_field = arcpy.Parameter(
                           displayName = "Output",
                           name = "Output_field",
                           datatype = "field",
                           parameterType = "Derived",
                           direction = "Output"
                                 )
   Output_field.ParameterDependency = ("in_features)

    #Add other parameters to the list                       
    params = ["Output_field",......]
    return params
```

You will need to update your parameters then fill the execute method

Comment: thank u for reading my question. I already created output parameter. I cant understand what you answered. i just want to solve that equation. and want to store output in input file.